# Spyder suddenly copies code to end of file

Tags: python, spyder

This happens to me regularly (maybe once a day) while I am using Spyder to edit my scripts, and I do not know what the reason is:

Suddenly, a copy of my code (sometimes also only a part of it) is replicated at the end of the editor.

This is not always immediately visible, so you continue to edit your code and suddenly realize that your changes do not have an effect - because the code that is actually executed is the one at the end of the file, not what you are editing.

I am not sure if this happens because I inadvertently hit a magic key combination, of if it is bug in Spyder.

Spyder version is 5.0.5, but I have seen this also in prior version. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Should be some keys striking in between like a copy-paste thing. Did you try opening a brand new text editor and do the same?

Comment: I have tried to pin it down to keys I strike, but I can never fix it to anything - because when I realize it, I don't know when it happened. And it only happens to me when working with Spyder, never with any other editors. So it's weird.
I believe it does not matter if I just opened the file or have already been working on it for a while.

Comment: That's WEIRD!! Try jupyter to see if the same pattern follows.

Comment: No, just spyder...

Comment: This seems to be a wider issue, I have filed a bug report and it should be fixed in the upcoming release. https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16280